# How much risk is there in securities lending?

Tags: united-states, risk, security-lending

I worked for a startup for many years and as a result I have a lot of shares in a company that went public via a SPAC deal. I know it's risky but I'm choosing to sell them over a period of a few years to reduce the tax impact.

Recently my brokerage (Fidelity) popped up an offer to [lend out my securities](https://www.fidelity.com/trading/fully-paid-lending), specifically my startup stock because it is in high demand (presumably due to heavy short interest). They claim an interest rate of 10.875%, and with the amount of shares I have the income would be quite substantial.

Obviously an ~11% interest rate in the current environment sounds too good to be true. I understand there is a default risk; how likely is this? Fidelity says it "provides collateral at a minimum of 100% of the loan value"; does this amount change with the stock price? My concern is if the value of the stock goes up, it would increase the default risk to somebody shorting it, at the same time it would increase the amount I would lose in such a scenario.

Is there anything else I should be aware of here?

EDIT: I believe this question is distinct from [What are the risks of allowing my stock broker to lend out my shares to short sellers?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/127139/what-are-the-risks-of-allowing-my-stock-broker-to-lend-out-my-shares-to-short-se) in that I would be opting in to lending out my shares and receiving significant interest, versus the type of lending that many brokerages do automatically and must be opted out of. I suspect the risk levels must be different (e.g. I would lose SIPC insurance).

Comment: Regarding [What are the risks of allowing my stock broker to lend out my shares to short sellers?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/127139/what-are-the-risks-of-allowing-my-stock-broker-to-lend-out-my-shares-to-short-se), it appears that Bob's answer is incorrect. I hope Bob clarifies the answer.

Comment: Is my answer still incorrect?

Comment: The details of Fidelity's [Fully Paid Lending Program](https://www.fidelity.com/bin-public/060_www_fidelity_com/documents/landing-zones/Fully-Paid-Lending-Program-Investor.pdf) are listed here. 1) In the Fully Paid Lending Program, Fidelity can borrow fully paid and excess-margin securities1 from your account. In return, you receive collateral held at a custodial bank independent of Fidelity. In the event of a default by Fidelity, you will have the right to withdraw the collateral from the custodial bank in the manner described in the agreements.

Comment: IF your shares offer options and IF the implied volatility is respectable and IF Fidelity lends your shares, I'd take a hard look at how many protective puts the lending fee would pay for thereby protecting a large amount of the principal. IF all of those conditions were met, not only would SIPC not matter but you'd have a protected long position with upside potential and modest downside risk.  Yeh, a lot of IFs but worth looking into.